# Are >? or <? legitimate operators in any C++ dialect?

Tags: c++, operators

I ran across the following lines of C++ code in a file (non-contiguous lines) that gcc 4.2.1 won't accept:

```
int frame = blk <? mBlkCnt-1;
mInsCnt = blk <? mBlkCnt;
mInsCnt = mInsCnt+1 <? mBlkCnt;
const int to_read = (mFileSz-byte_off) <? mBlkSz;
```

Both `<?` and `>?` are used in various places in the code. They appear to be a shorthand for assigning the smaller (or larger) of two values, but I've never seen this operator combination.  Any ideas on what this is?

Comment: A Google search doesn't turn up a single hit for that character combination.  Perhaps its a character encoding failure during a cut and paste operation.

Comment: @Amardeep: Google doesn't turn up a single hit for ++ either. You can't google for punctuation.

Comment: @sepp2K:  Thanks... it wouldn't make much sense to index punctuation, would it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

They're called the [min and max operators](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Min-and-Max.html) and were language extensions in earlier versions of gcc.

They are no longer supported.

Comment: Refs: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_5.html#SEC107 http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html#Deprecated-Features

Comment: +1 for enlightening us but I'm glad they're gone from GCC.  I'd hate to see C++ suffer from what happened to Java when Microsoft did their Visual J++ extensions.

Comment: That's a funny link. "However, writing MIN and MAX as macros also forces you to use function-call notation for a fundamental arithmetic operation." Min and max are "fundamental arithmetic operations"?

Comment: The MIN and MAX macros in the gcc 3.3.6 docs linked above look wrong     #define MIN(X,Y) ((X) < (Y) ? : (X) : (Y)) -- extra colon

Comment: @User: The author probably slipped up and used another extension, the binary `?:` operator. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.1/gcc/Conditionals.html - this one isn't deprecated, but rather works like `||` does in Python and other languages.

Comment: I believe that the extensions in C (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) also apply to C++.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a C++ operator, that's for sure. It almost resembles a digraph, but certainly not a valid one. In any case, a digraph, if supported, would just result in punctuation, not a whole new operator.

So, in answer to your question, perhaps this file needs to be preprocessed by some preprocessor that converts it to valid C++.

Comment: examples of digraphs are <% and %> which represent { and } respectively